# Angularfire unable to define ref

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to connect to firebase from Angular JS.

My controller:

```
.controller('mynew',['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var ref = firebase.database('https://myappurl.firebaseio.com/contacts').ref();
    $scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(ref);
    console.log($scope.contacts);
}]);
```

Is this the proper way to include the firebase db url in `database(??)`?

The versions: 
Firebase v3.6.9
Angularfire v2.3.0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your firebase database this way (omit the data you don't need):

```
 // Initialize the Firebase SDK
  var config = {
    apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Then after that database() will be intialized.

See this from docs:

```
app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  // download the data into a local object
  $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
  // putting a console.log here won't work, see below
});
```

See the docs here for [getting started](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a ton. Is there a page i can refer to for documentation on queries on firebase from AngularJS. NOT Angular2. Just simple queries. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Heres the docs for [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html) :)